# adjective for "wanting/in the mood to watch a movie"

Tags: phrases, adjectives, synonyms

Are there adjectives that describe this phrase? I will be using this term as an individual, one-word responses on a form, so sentence usage is unimportant.

For example:
**"Wanting to date"** would be **"Flirty"**
-or-
**"Wanting to eat"** would be **"Hungry"**

Phrase:
**"Wanting to watch a movie"**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum. Questions here need to show evidence of attempted research, and should ask about only one thing at a time. Word and phrase requests should also, at a minimum, demonstrate how the word or phrase you are seeking would be used in a sentence. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: @choster How would I show that I've done research? With search engines being keyword-based, it's very difficult to formulate a question that would give you the results you are looking for.  All of these words will used on  their own as one-word responses in a form, which I have edited the question to clear up. If I can't ask these sort of things here, could you suggest a forum where I can ask? Thanks.

Comment: "I'm feeling film-y / learn-y / inside-y / outside-y / drink-y / explore-y"

Comment: Generally, it's required that you ask one question at a time. I know that these are all related but you're asking half a dozen questions at once.

Comment: I stiill don't think you understand how StackExchange works. You can't ask for seven words in a single question; it's impossible to answer and vote in our format. For some reasonable recent single word requests, I might point you to *[Looking for an English word or expression for not having a real boss in charge](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/339403)* and *['Predator' is to 'Predatory' as 'Prey' is to…?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/339009)*

Comment: Restless, for new places

Comment: @Thinkatron Dictionaries are quite good places to look for related words.

Comment: What would you suggest I do? Should I just delete the question? I didn't think about the upvote system, the only times I've used stack exchange is in stackoverflow where the questions are programming related, so I've never run into an issue where asking multiple questions would be problematic, as they would usually be solved with the same answer. I ask with multiple posts, but that would flood the questions section. Again, if you know of another forum where this kind of question would be acceptable, please direct me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### (wanting to watch a movie)

I think **escapist** (adjective) is as close as you're gonna get:

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/escapist)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Providing or seeking distraction and relief from unpleasant realities, especially in the form of entertainment or fantasy:
>
> *I was ready for a good **escapist** read*
>
> *the **escapist** desires of the moviegoing public*

---

***as for your other requests:***

---

### (wanting to learn new information)

**inquisitive**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inquisitive)

> 1. given to inquiry, research, or asking questions; eager for knowledge; intellectually curious

**curious**

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/curious)

> Eager to know or learn something

---

### (wanting to stay inside)

**indoorsy**

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indoorsy)

> Favouring, or pertaining to, indoor life.

**homey**

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homey)

> Befitting a home; cozy, intimate.

---

### (wanting to go outside)

**outdoorsy**

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outdoorsy)

> : enjoying outdoor activities

---

### (wanting to see new places)

**explorative**

[thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/explorative)

> serving in or intended for exploration or discovery

---

### (desire for alcohol)

**boozy**

[Oxford learner's dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/boozy)

> liking to drink a lot of alcohol; involving a lot of alcoholic drink

**dipsomanic** (strong desire for alcohol)

[Oxford learner's dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/dipsomaniac)

> [having] a strong desire for alcoholic drink that they cannot control

---

### (wanting to be thrilled)

**thrill-seeking**

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/thrill-seeking)

> adjective: Keen to take part in exciting activities that involve physical risk

---

Comment: Thanks very much! I've edited the answer now to not show all of the original phrases to better match the upvote system, but your answer is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The closest adjective I can think of would be:

> Cinephilic: Having a love of films or the cinema. [(reference)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cinephilic)

Which is related to the more commonly known noun:

> Cinephile: A devotee of motion pictures. [(reference)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cinephile)

Comment: I was thinking that, but I feel like the negative connotation of "phile" would drive people away. (I'm using this for an app I'm developing.)

Comment: Yes I guess, it's almost two different questions really. The first is to do with what the most accurate terms in English are, and the second is more a marketing question, about what phrase should be used to market a product. If you are not too concerned with literary appeal, and more seeking to go for sheer marketing value, I quite like "movie hungry".